# What is the proper (practical/efficient) way to analyze a sentence?

Tags: grammar, objects, subjects

One is given the sample sentence:

> The fat blind man ran from the dog.

What are the procedural steps to deduce the subject and predicate from the sentence? What are the general steps to completely analyze the sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionary.com on *[subject](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/subject)*:

> **9.**  *Grammar* (in English and many other languages) a syntactic unit that functions as one of the two main constituents of a simple sentence, the other being the predicate, and that consists of a noun, noun phrase, or noun substitute which often refers to the one performing the action or being in the state expressed by the predicate, as *He* in *He gave notice*.

On *[predicate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/predicate)*:

> **8.** *Grammar* (in many languages, as English) a syntactic unit that functions as one of the two main constituents of a simple sentence, the other being the subject, and that consists of a verb, which in English may agree with the subject in number, and of all the words governed by the verb or modifying it, the whole often expressing the action performed by or the state attributed to the subject, as *is here* in *Larry is here*.

The **subject**, then is defined as the subject noun (e.g. *man*) along with the words which modify the noun (e.g. *the fat blind*).  The **predicate** is the verb (e.g. *ran*), direct object (*none in this sentence*), and any modifying adverbs or prepositional phrases (e.g. *from the dog*):

> Subject = *The fat blind man*
>   Predicate = *ran from the dog*.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanky you. What would you do for a more complex sentence such as `The fat blind man ran from the dog while throwing darts at a penguin.`? Would the latter part of the the sentence be considered a (implicity) a new sentence?

Comment: No, it is still a single sentence, but now it is a *complex sentence*, composed of two clauses, which are connected by the conjunction *while*.  Each clause has its own subject and predicate, though the second clause is elliptic and has no subject, so it must be understood to exist.  To break it down: [The fat blind man] [ran from the dog] [while] [ *he* ] [ *was* throwing darts at a penguin] = [Subject 1] [predicate 1] [conjunction] [subject 2] [predicate 2].